# Why does Cytoscape not launch for most users on a Windows system?

Tags: crash, freeze, launch, cytoscape

Having an issue on some Azure Virtual Desktop VMs running Windows 10 Mutli-Session 22H2 with Cytoscape application opening.   For many users, when they go to open Cytoscape it will sit at the Initializing prompt / splash screen and not progress forward.  Task Manager shows Cytoscape at 0% CPU.  It will sit until you end the task.  It doesnt timeout or crash, just sits there at Initializing.   Sometimes, if you end the task is Task Manager and start the app again, it will load fully and open.  But that doesnt always happen either, its like a crap shoot.

Several of these users are even admins on the VMs and the issues happen.  What is stranger is that for the admins that it hangs for, if they chose to Run As Administrator to open it, Cytoscape will fully launch and open.

I know its an odd issue, but I have no idea what the cause is here.   We have had Cytoscape running on our image for a while.   The revision of the image we have in production right now runs and launches it fine.  But the new image version that we want to deploy out is where we are seeing the issues.  The only differences in the images are the addition of JMP Pro, Simio and 3M CRS applications added.

Looking for any advice here.

I tried logging into each VM as local admin and opening Cytoscape.  The app opens without fail.  But still fails on same VM when anyone logs in with their domain account.

We have had this app running in our virtual labs for a while, so this issue is brand new.

Checked into the Java version being an issue by running the checker application and it said Java version is wrong, but the fact the app launches fine on the current production revision of our image and it opens for local admin account on the updated image,  tells me Java is not the issue.  I just dont know why the local admin can run it, but users and admins that login with domain accounts cannot.

Java on both the VMs it is working and loading on as well as the VMs that it is hanging at initializing

openjdk version "11.0.16.1" 2022-08-12 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-40648 (build 11.0.16.1+1-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Microsoft-40648 (build 11.0.16.1+1-LTS, mixed mode)

Windows Event Log first shows

Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: AppHangB1
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: Cytoscape.exe
P2: 0.0.0.0
P3: 6377c6fe
P4: 997f
P5: 67246080
P6:
P7:
P8:
P9:
P10:

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\Critical_Cytoscape.exe_aea072bd4dc6213c7ffcbbe5cb0eb3b22a888b9_5e70064d_a19dc0d2-e227-4b5c-b8a4-52a9f6a35933

Analysis symbol:
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 35e10914-779e-49e5-8293-5fc51d15364a
Report Status: 4
Hashed bucket:
Cab Guid: 0

Followed by Application Hang error

The program Cytoscape.exe version 0.0.0.0 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel.
Process ID: 53bc
Start Time: 01d9e3ffc17b8e54
Termination Time: 4294967295
Application Path: C:\Program Files\Cytoscape_v3.10.0\Cytoscape.exe
Report Id: 35e10914-779e-49e5-8293-5fc51d15364a
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
Hang type: Top level window is idle

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to hear you are having problems.  My first suggestion is to try running cytoscape.bat from a command window.  You'll need to make sure you have the right Java installed and your `JAVA_HOME` pointed to it (double-clicking on the icon will use the version of Java we bundle, but cytoscape.bat doesn't use that).  You should get some information about where things are as it runs.

My guess is that there is some sort of permissions issue.  Cytoscape wants to write its karaf cache files on startup and that may be causing you problems.

Comment: Please refrain from adding signatures here - the profile card is considered to be enough

Comment: Good afternoon Scooter - just a quick reminder on signatures. There is canonical advice on Meta SO available if you need it. Stack Overflow is not a forum or a chatroom.